# Which error outputs can I expect from PHP?

Tags: php, error-handling

I want to build a regex that matches PHP-style error messages in HTML source code.

Does anybody know of one that exists or how I can create a list of possible PHP error outputs?

Comment: Why would you want to do that? Do you plan to remove error messages after they were reported?

Comment: Wow, I'd love to hear what's the purpose of this

Comment: Why does everyone try to do everything with regex's nowadays?

Comment: Nah, I'm writing a browser extension that displays a symbol when there are PHP errors in the HTML source code (as they're not always visible).

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at the PHP source code, there should be a function to wrap errors and try to guess the convention used for all errors, warning, notices messages.

Answer (score 1):

Depending on what you're actually trying to accomplish (you weren't very specific), I would instead recommend using [`set_error_handler`](http://uk.php.net/set_error_handler).

```
function myErrorHandler($errno, $errstr, $errfile, $errline) {
  // handle and log the error appropriately
}

set_error_handler("myErrorHandler");
```

Comment: Seriously, if I say I want to match PHP-style error messages, this is not what I want to do ;)
I hope my comment above explains better...

Comment: @Franz: Okay, now I know why you want to do this :) If you had included that information in the question right away, I wouldn't have posted this answer ;)

Answer (score 0):

You can see a list of PHP's [Predefined Constants](https://www.php.net/manual/en/errorfunc.constants.php).

Every error/warning/notice will fall into one of these categories, however there are likely hundreds if not thousands of possible messages which PHP can throw.